# Send data, view model with IFormFile if form with unobtrusive-ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, iformfile

I have a form in a separate view MyAddForm.cshtml

```
@model MyViewModel

<form id="my_form" class="form-inline" asp-action="MyAddForm" asp-controller="Profile" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#my_form" data-ajax-method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        <input class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" asp-for="Name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label asp-for="Image"></label>
        <input asp-for="Image" type="file" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
...
</form>
```

there is ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [FileExtensions(Extensions = "jpg,jpeg")]
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}
```

and there is Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAddForm(MyViewModel model)
{
    //model.Image always null...
    ...
    return PartialView("~/Views/Profile/MyAddFormForm.cshtml", model);
}
```

the problem is that if the form has the attribute: data-ajax="true", then in the Controller the model arrives without a downloaded file (null). This is because the "Content-Type" header is not set to "multipart / form-date", although it is indicated on the form.

I need the result to return exactly through "unobtrusive-ajax", how in this case to implement sending the viewModel together with the file?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use $ajax jquery, this is what you need and it works. But I do not understand why the submit is confirmed 2-3 times, instead of one ...

```
$(document).on("submit", '#my_form', function (event) {
    var formdata = new FormData($('#my_form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAddForm", "Profile")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function (result) {
        $('#my_form').html(result);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**UPDATE2:**

In this construction: "`$(document).on("submit", '#my_form', function (event) {}`" the default action cancel event does not work by default, because of this there is a double sending of data...

I had to insert this code, after calling ajax, which rendered the form itself:

```
...
}).done(function (result) {
    $('#add_cat').html(result);
    ...
    $('#my_form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Now the cancellation event works
        var formdata = new FormData($('#my_form')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("MyAddForm", "Profile")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function (result) {
            $('#my_form').html(result);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And now it works :)
Sorry for my English...